# Codeigniter 3.0.3 routes issue

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a controller called Wsdl :

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Wsdl extends MY_Controller {
    public function wsdl() {
    }
    public function wsdl_edit($id) {
    }
}
```

the wsdl edit takes `1` parameter `$id` that must be number.

now the `wsdl_edit` method is accessible via this url : `mywebsite.com/admin/wsdl/wsdl_edit/1`

When `1` is missing I show a page error.
When something no a number is used like `mywebsite.com/admin/wsdl/wsdl_edit/xx`
I show an error.
I'm trying to make that in the route config like :

```
$route['wsdl/(:num)'] = "wsdl/wsdl_edit/$1";
$route['wsdl/(:any)'] = "wsdl/wsdl_edit/error";
$route['wsdl'] = "wsdl/wsdl_edit/error";
```

but it is not working any help please?

Answer (score 1):

You have two contradicting routes:

```html
$route['wsdl/(:num)'] = "wsdl/wsdl_edit/$1"; 

$route['wsdl/(:any)'] = "wsdl/wsdl_edit/error";
```

First of all, you missed out on 'wsdl_edit'. So your routes should be

```html
$route['wsdl/wsdl_edit/(:num)'] = "wsdl/wsdl_edit/$1"; 
//Works if an integer is the parameter after wsdl/wsdl_edit/

$route['wsdl/wsdl_edit/(:any)'] = "wsdl/wsdl_edit/error"; 
//Works if anything is the parameter after wsdl/wsdl_edit/ including integer. 
//This route will override the above rule and will be executed.
```

You can always check this $id in the function too, getting rid of the routes:

```html
 public function wsdl_edit($id) {
    
    # Check if your variable is an integer
    if( filter_var($id, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT) !== false ){
      redirect('error.php') // when $id is not an integer.
    }
}
else{ //Your desired action
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

you forgot the `wsdl_edit` method in your route rule

```
$route['wsdl/wsdl_edit/(:num)'] = "wsdl/wsdl_edit/$1";
$route['wsdl/wsdl_edit/(:any)'] = "wsdl/wsdl_edit/error";
```

Or if you prefer using Regular Expressions

```
$route['wsdl/wsdl_edit/([0-9]+)'] = "wsdl/wsdl_edit/$1";
$route['wsdl/wsdl_edit/.+'] = "wsdl/wsdl_edit/error";
```

> Note: Routes will run in the order they are defined. Higher routes
>   will always take precedence over lower ones.